# Hiera value not able to receiving in puppet profile

Tags: puppet, hiera

1. I have created a proxy_match.yaml file as  a hiera source file in
   default hiera datalocation.
2. The proxy_match.yaml is added in hiera hierarchy
3. Looking up hiera data in profile

> Where and what am I missing, I am not able to receive the hiera data
>   value and thus the error appears mentioned bellow.

**Where,**
*proxy_match is the new environment created*

**hierafile 1**
*/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/proxy_match/hiera.yaml*

```
version: 5
defaults:
  # The default value for "datadir" is "data" under the same directory as the hiera.yaml
  # file (this file)
  # When specifying a datadir, make sure the directory exists.
  # See https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/environments.html for further details on environments.
  # datadir: data
  # data_hash: yaml_data


hierarchy:
  - name: "environment specific yaml"
    path: "proxy_match.yaml"
  - name: "Per-node data (yaml version)"
    path: "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}.yaml"
  - name: "Other YAML hierarchy levels"
    paths:
      - "common.yaml"
```

**proxy_match.yaml hiera data source file**

*This is the yaml hiera source named as proxy_match.yaml as in herarchy*
*/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/proxy_match/data/proxy-match.yaml*

```
---
profiles::apache::servername: "taraserver.com"
profiles::apache::port: "80"
profiles::apache::docroot: "/var/www/tarahost"
```

**hiera lookup in profile**

```
$servername  = hiera('profiles::apache::servername',{})
  $port        = hiera('profiles::apache::port',{})
  $docroot     = hiera('profiles::apache::docroot',{})
  class profile::apache{
    #configure apache
    include apache
    apache::vhost{$servername:
      port    => $port,
      docroot => $docroot,
    }
  }
```

**#ERROR:**

---

```
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: {"message":"Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Apache::Vhost[7fba80ae621c.domain.name]: parameter 'docroot' expects a value of type Boolean or String, got Undef at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/proxy_match/modules/profile/manifests/apache.pp:29 on node 94707b03ff05.domain.name","issue_kind":"RUNTIME_ERROR"}
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the variables outside the class definition. When Puppet loads that class, those lines you have before the class are ignored.

What you should have in your profile class is:

```
class profiles::apache (
  String $servername,
  Integer $port,
  String $docroot,
) {
  include apache
  apache::vhost { $servername:
    port    => $port,
    docroot => $docroot,
  }
}
```

Note that I used the [automatic parameter lookup](https://puppet.com/docs/hiera/3.3/puppet.html#automatic-parameter-lookup) feature to set your variables, instead of explicit calls to the hiera function.

Comment: If you wanted to use automatic parameter lookup (and why not for this situation), you would also need to correct the typo in the asker's class definition (`profile` vs. `profiles`). Also would suggest adding a recommendation to make this module data and not env data if it will use auto data bindings, and to not use `hiera()` with Hiera >= 4..

Comment: I haven't used these new features yet to be honest. The module layer is said to be a "convenient alternative to params.pp" so I think you mean the data belongs in the environment layer, unless I'm misreading the docs. Typo fixed.

Comment: Well since using automatic parameter lookup heavily implies the hieradata is specific to one module, it follows that the hieradata should be located at the module level and not the global or environment level. We have to infer this though and cannot know for sure.

Comment: Maybe it has changed, but historically, declarations at top scope such as those you point out *were not* ignored, though they do constitute a dastardly source of error.  Since they are at top scope they apply to every node, even those that do not include the class, but because of their location, their declarations might not always be parsed.  But when they *are* parsed, they may be cached.  It all makes for quite a mess, and sometimes tricky to diagnose misbehavior.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I feel like top-scope is anything that exists in a catalog above the node definition level and that this is a "no scope" since the class is included and not the entire manifest file, as would be the case in an `apply` on the manifest. Thus, the variable initializations are ignored and this answer fixes the issue.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, the fundamental rule here is (or maybe *was*) that evaluating a manifest file has the same significance and effect regardless of *why* it is evaluated (e.g. to try to obtain a definition of a particular class).  A declaration of a resource or a variable is at top scope if it appears outside any class, node, or defined-type definition.  Such declarations are absolutely permitted and meaningful in the site manifest, and therefore also in other manifests.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That is a compelling argument, and my assumption in this case would be that the variables are discarded after parsing. I would assume this kind of thing is not going to be in the documentation and would require digging around in the source code for verification.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, the definitive documentation on scope is [in the language reference](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_scope.html).  Do note that the definition of top scope has nothing to do with the name or location of the manifest file, or with the circumstances of its evaluation.  Furthermore, declarations at top scope are not dropped at the end of evaluation of one file.  Puppet scope is not fundamentally *lexical*, but rather semantic.  There is only one top scope for any catalog-building run, and once a variable gets in, it does not come out.

Comment: So, if it helps, I tested it before I wrote this. If you place this code in a file init.pp and then puppet apply it, the variables are set. If you place the code in an init.pp file inside a module in the modulepath, then the variables are not set. I would have thought that the "top scope" is code in the site.pp file rather than here?

Comment: @AlexHarvey Thanks made my days was pondering 2 days for it a silly mistakes. Also your reply made me clear about parameter auto  lookup. Would be  so great if you could provide  me some more info on `making it modular data not env data`

Comment: @AlexHarvey Unfortunately i didn't realize that though the errors does not exists but the virtualhost is not create . I have checked the docroot path and that doesnot exists.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Unfortunately i didn't realize that though the errors does not exists but the virtualhost is not created . I have checked the docroot path and that doesnot exists. Even trying to display the value fetched using notify is not displaying it . where might have the problem been. I created a `yaml file` with my environment name and added to `data folder` as we know that is the default datadir.

Comment: Obviously, there are other bugs in the code, but there is no information here that could tell me what the problem is.